# bogus "use of local variable with automatic storage from containing function" with c++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Following code does not compile in g++7.2.0

```
template <class Internal>
class Request {
    int content = 0;
public:
    friend void setContent(int i, void *voidptr) {
        Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<int>*)voidptr;
        ptr->content = i;
    }
    int getContent() {return content;}
};

int main() {
    Request<int> req;
    setContent(4, &req);
    return req.getContent();
}
```

With error

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void setContent(int, void*)’:
test.cpp:14:23:   required from here
test.cpp:7:14: error: use of local variable with automatic storage from containing function
         ptr->content = i;
         ~~~~~^~~~~~~
test.cpp:6:28: note: ‘Request<Internal>* ptr’ declared here
         Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<int>*)voidptr;
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this (apart from being stupid example). Clang 4.0.1 seems to accept it and I am pretty sure it compiled under g++ 5.4 
Also: if I remove all templates, this compiles ok.

Is this bug in compiler or I violate some rule I don't know?

EDIT
It seems it stopped working beginning with gcc 7.x https://godbolt.org/g/D6gqcF

Comment: I can confirm it compiles with no errors under g++ 6.3.0 also.

Comment: Aside: You probably want to cast the `void *` to `Request<Internal> *` rather than `Request<int> *` if you ever intend to instantiate this template with a different type

Comment: @Caleth true, but does not change anything. This was mistake in prepared example, not actual code

Comment: How are you intending to distinguish the multiple definitions of `void setContent(int, void *)` that multiple instantiations of this template will add to the enclosing namespace scope?

Comment: @Caleth I think you are onto the problem, because swapping `int` for `Internal` in declaration of `friend void setContent(int i, void *voidptr)` makes it pass. Though that would be a rather cryptic way of spelling this.

Comment: Knowing the code this comes from, template probably is instantiated with only one class, so template is unnecessary and would fail if instantiated more than once...

Comment: @luk32 are you sure? https://godbolt.org/g/kN9Eqm seems to not compile

Comment: @MateuszL You didn't swap `int` for `Internal`. See: https://godbolt.org/g/fhavbY . Clang complains only when you actually create a conflict with another instantation.

Comment: I've striped your example down a little and found something alone the same lines said above. In this you can see the difference: https://godbolt.org/g/7pe788

Comment: bolov good presentation - thank you. @luk32 I think clang behaves more correctly - code is bad but doesn't actually create conflicting instantiation; however I intentionally didn't swap int - it should be int, Internal is only to introduce template which is used in actual code and not in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether GCC is *legitimately* balking at this construction, but it seems like the total lack of `Request<Internal>` in the *type* of `setContent` is confusing it. The only reason you can refer to `Request<Internal>` is the injected class name, that comes from the scope of the definition.

```
template <class Internal>
class Request {
    int content = 0;
public:
    friend void setContent(int i, void *voidptr); // shouldn't make a difference
    int getContent() {return content;}
};

void setContent(int i, void * voidptr)
{
    // Where does Internal come from?
    Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<Internal>*)voidptr; 
    ptr->content = i;
}
```

I don't think you want a template here, because if you instantiate it with a second type you violate the one definition rule.

```
class RequestBase {
    int content = 0;
public:
    virtual ~RequestBase() = default;
    friend void setContent(int i, RequestBase * ptr) {
        ptr->content = i;
    }
    int getContent() {return content;}
};
```

If there are other members of your class, which use `Internal`, you can add them with a template subclass

```
template <class Internal>
class Request : public RequestBase {
    // members involving Internal
};
```

The other alternative is that you use `Internal` in the arguments to `setContent`

```
template <class Internal>
class Request {
    Internal content = 0;
public:
    friend void setContent(Internal i, void *voidptr){
        Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<Internal>*)voidptr;
        ptr->content = i;
    }
    Internal getContent() {return content;}
};
```

or

```
template <class Internal>
class Request {
    int content = 0;
public:
    friend void setContent(int i, Request<Internal> *ptr) {
        ptr->content = i;
    }
    int getContent() {return content;}
};
```

note that you can still bind `void setContent(int, Request<Internal> *)` to a `void (*)(int, void *)` function pointer etc

Comment: quoting the OP: "I don't understand what is wrong with this (apart from being stupid example)" so I don't think the answer to the question is to find an alternate design as the core of the problem is how gcc is dealing with this particular example.

Comment: While obviously, that's a better idea to write actual code, I don't think it answers the real question, whether compiler is allowed to refuse the code or not.

Comment: Couldn't find anything in [basic.def.odr, class.friend, temp.dep, temp.friend or temp.inject](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659) to suggest that the code is ill-formed – as long as the template is instantiated at most once. But you are right to point out that this is very bad style.

Comment: Ok, so my current theory is that the code is shitty (I knew it before) and gcc since 7.x is confused by its faults. I am pretty sure that in no scope there is actually multiple setContent definitions, because if there were previous versions would not compile as well. I will have to think how to apply one of suggestions. Sadly actual code is more like friend void setContent(int i, http_parser *parser) {Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<Internal>*) parser->data;... where http_parser is not templated and data is void*, so multiple changes are needed

Answer (score 1):

This one looks genuinely tricky. Let's look at the line again:

`Request<Internal> *ptr = (Request<int>*)voidptr;`

Those are two *different* types. How do you convert between one type and another? Well, the obvious way would be a derived-to-base conversion.

Now, you may say that `Request<int>` is not a derived class. If we look at the whole program, that's true. But in the first phase of template compilation, the compiler hasn't seen any template specializations *yet*. There may still be a specialization of `Request<int>` that could introduce a base class later down the road (!)

I'd have to grab appropriate C++ standards to check is something subtle changed in this area, but from an engineering point is comes as no surprise when such code proves fragile in the face of minor compiler changes.